# Insert a calculated field in a pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a calculated field in this pivot table. it should calculate the NPS score as Promoters - Detractors / Grand Total. I don't what should be the formula

[image]

i tried this code but it gives an error
=(GETPIVOTDATA("Promoter", [NPS_Group]) - GETPIVOTDATA("Detractor", [NPS_Group])) / GETPIVOTDATA("Grand Total", [NPS_Group])

I also tried to calculate on the sheet itself using a macro but that keeps giving an error as well

```
Sheets.Add.Name = "Filtered"
Set wsout = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Filtered")


Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Table1")
Set pvtTable = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=wsout.Range("A3"), TableName:="PivotTable1")

With wsout.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Staff_Name")
    For Each Pi In .PivotItems
        Item = Pi.Name
        For i = 5 To .PivotItems.Count
        wsout.Range("F" & i) = wsout.PivotTables("PivotTable1").GetPivotData("NPS_Group", A3, "NPS_Group", "Promoter", _
        "Staff_Name", Item) - wsout.PivotTables("PivotTable1").GetPivotData("NPS_Group", A3, "NPS_Group", "Detractor", _
        "Staff_Name", Item) / wsout.PivotTables("PivotTable1").GetPivotData("NPS_Group", A3)
        Next i
        
    Next Pi
End With
```